# Flat table to tree view

Tags: php, mysql, database, treeview, yii

[image]I got a Post table in my DB (for my tree-based forum system)
all **posts** are children of a **Topic** (you can see in my example the field topicId which is 79)
what I do is SELECT all the rows which has topicId 79 (in this specific example)

so now, I got all the posts of topic #79
you can see the field parentId. if the Post is reply to the topic the value is NULL
otherwise, the Post is a child of another Post so it has the id of the parent post.

now, as I said I have all the rows of topic #79
and I need to display them in a tree view

what is the best way to do it?

by the way, I'm using PHP+MySQL powered by Yii Framework (and don't want to use zii widgets)

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Recursion.

1.First , have a loop which gets all the "parents posts" (a post with parentId=null).

2.For each "parent post" summon a recursive function which will print the post's details and will summon itself for its child posts.

I didn't check the code , but this is the main concept which will help you with your problem.

```
function build_tree_child($post_id,$level=0)
{
 $post = get_post_byId($post_id);
 foreach($i = 0; $i <$level;$i++) echo "&nbsp;"; //Simple trick to make it LOOK like a tree
 echo $post['title'];

 $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE parentId='$post_id'");
 while($childs = mysql_fetch_array($q))
  build_tree_child($child['id'] , $level++);

}
```

Comment: is it efficient to make all this queries only for showing a topic thread?

Comment: You're using YiiFramework , I guess it support Active Record and cache.